# KonvaJS different strokes

Tags: reactjs, rectangles, konvajs, stroke

I have a rectangle in KonvaJS:

```
    <Rect
       x={200}
       y={20}
       width={300}
       height={150}
       fill="yellow"
       shadowBlur={3}
       b
       draggable
       rotation={90}
       strokeWidth={4}
    />
```

How can I made custom stroke width for rectangles? for example: **5px stroke width for top border, 3px stroke width for bottom border, 2px for left, and right border?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Konva doesn't support that. Use several lines instead.